# How to get rid of everything in a text widget

Tags: python, user-interface

my program is a bit too long to put up here so...

basically what is it is that it creates a short story using the inputs entered by the user, and I wanted to allow the user re-enter new data and create another story. So basically, and it was part of the requirement that I need to use insert and delete method.

```
self.story.delete( ????? )
self.story.insert( ????? )
```

Comment: Simple, just write the `delete()` and `insert()` methods, and instead of the question marks insert the parameters you want to pass to them.

Comment: @MarkThomas sorry I actually never learned the delete and insert, I have no idea what kind of parameters should I place in the brackets

Comment: @Cyber it is a string

Comment: @MandyQuan strings are immutable, you cannot modify them.

Comment: @Cyber alright I putted it in a list now, should be fine now... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very, very simple. Literally a quick google search.
But, here's how to do it:

```
text.delete(1.0, END)
```

Since you didn't show any code, I don't know what you want before `.delete`

I'm assuming this is Tkinter as well.
More info here:
[Click](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: may I ask what is that 1.0?

Comment: @MandyQuan It is the line index position.